# Select sum of column from a table where column has specific text

Tags: mysql, select, sum, concatenation

I have this table where we add all the services for the companies vehicles.

I want to select the sum from the column price from which the vehicles where serviced by this two specific companies.

The first company is called **A.G Trucks LTD** and other one **LC Trucks SERVICE STATION LTD**. The column of these is `servicedby`.

Currently I use this of which has no results:

```
case 'getstats':

            $q=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
            $query="SELECT sum(price) FROM `Service` Where `servicedby` = 'Trucks' ";

            $result = mysql_query($query);


            $temp=0;
            $json = array();
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $json[$temp]['servicedby'] = $row['servicedby'];
                    $json[$temp]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $temp++;
                }

            print json_encode($json);




            mysql_close();


        break;
```

So how can I select:

*sum(price) FROM Service Where 'servicedby' **CONTAINS 'trucks'***

Both columns price and servicedby are Varchar.

Comment: lookup sql's `LIKE` or `REGEXP` or possibly `FULLTEXT` functionality, although I would say FULLTEXT doesn't fit this particular scenerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM `Service` Where `servicedby` like '%Trucks%'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different ways to solve your problem.

You can use the IN clause:

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM `Service` Where `servicedby` IN ('A.G Trucks LTD','LC Trucks SERVICE STATION LTD')
```

You can use the LIKE clause:

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM `Service` Where `servicedby` LIKE '%Trucks%'
```

Comment: `in` is nice, but is too strict to answer: `Where 'servicedby' CONTAINS 'trucks'`